# Using curl for scraping large pages

Tags: php, curl, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape comments from a popular news site for an academic study using curl. It works fine for articles with <300 comments but after that it struggles.

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$html = curl_exec($handle);
curl_close($handle);
echo $html; //just to see what's been scraped
```

At the moment this page works fine: http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2012/aug/22/letter-from-india-women-drink?commentpage=all#start-of-comments

But this one only returns 36 comments despite there being 700+ in total: http://www.guardian.co.uk/commentisfree/2012/aug/21/everyones-talking-about-rape?commentpage=all#start-of-comments

Why is it struggling for articles with a ton of comments?

Comment: You should check out [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)...

Comment: There is uses pagination. You need to know the number of pages and using cycle get comments from each page.

Answer (score 2):

You comments page is pageinated.  Each page contains differerent comments.  You will have to request all comment pagination links.

The parameter `page=x` is appended to the url for a different page.

It might be good to get base page then search for all links with page paarameter and request each of those in turn?

As Mike Christensen pointed out if you could use python and scrapy that functionality is built in.  You just have to specify the element the comment is located in and python will crawl all links on the page for you:)

Comment: BTW, if you're scared of rewriting your project or don't want to learn new stuff... I got Scrapy up and running and crawling some data off a department store website within about 20 min, and I had never written a line of Python in my life!

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. 

I got over the pagination problem by appending "?commentpage=all" onto the url executing the curl. It works fine for pages with up to 350 comments but after that the pagination kicks in again and it only scrapes the last 50 or so comments. It almost feels like the curl request isn't executed completely or is being timed out. I tried extending the CURLOPT_TIMEOUT to 60 seconds to give it enough time to complete the task but this didn't seem to help.

I'll definitely check out Scrapy but I've never used Python and my deadline's pretty close.

Thanks again!